# MS Visual Studio problems?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My professor wants us to submit our project in MS Visual Studio 2013. At first I didn't realize this and just made a .cpp and .h file in a folder on my desktop, where after I ran g++ myFile.cpp, /a.out does everything I need.
However... I tried copying the two files into a MS Visual Studio 2013 Project, when I build and run it I see a terminal open and close very quicklly
(I am in Console Application). What doesn't make sense to me is my program has Cin's and requires user input. How come I don't see any of the couts and it is not taking any input? Thanks
edit:this is my first time using visual studio

The output is this:

```
'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

\'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\rvalent4\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread 0x9f0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

The thread 0x1038 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

'ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\rvalent4\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe'. Symbols loaded.

The thread 0x114 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

The thread 0x14c4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).

The program '[1880] ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: That output is indeed interesting, but seeing the source code of the program you want to run would be even better.

Comment: it is just a simple school project where I cin asking for an input file, and output file. then I transfer all the characters in the input into the output and cout the cpu timed. it worked perfectly on my linux desktop. I'm not sure if that would make a difference now that this is windows since it is still just a simple .cpp

Comment: Did you select a `Win32 Console Application` project?  Your issue looks like you chose something other than a console project.

Comment: I don't think I did, I do remember him mentioning the words Win32 Console in class. Where would I find that? I only saw Console Application

Comment: @user2770808 `File -> New -> Project`  Make sure you see `Visual C++` as the template and choose `Win32 Console Application`.

Comment: You selected a .NET / CLR application.

Comment: Your app is running and then exiting. All that output is due to you making a managed (.Net/CLR) project. If you want to see your run results, either put a breakpoint on the last line of executing code, or add a "press any key to continue" functionality to the end of your main function code.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is a vanilla C++ application (or one that uses the Win32 API in some way), then choose

`File -> New -> Project...` and make sure that you see `Visual C++` as a template.

Then choose `Win32 Console Application` as the project type.

Once the project is selected, you can either edit the `main.cpp` file, or remove the `main.cpp` file from your project and add the ones you were given by your professor (assuming your source files has a `main()` function defined).

The project should build ok, barring any compiler and linker errors.

The next step is to run your program correctly.  You can either start the debugger `(F10 key)`, set a breakpoint at the end of the `main()` function, and `(F5 key)` to continue running.